# How to "mark" a UL/LI nav item as "active" based on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Each `<a` link is an anchor for jQuery to hide(show) certain divs.

I'm using this CSS to handle hover style:

```
ul.textMenu a:hover

{   
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff5c00;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

After the user clicks an item, I want that `border-bottom` to persist.  How do I do this?

[image: menu]

Comment: Show what you have so far in your JavaScript. Where are you stuck? What don't you know how to do?

Comment: Who would upvote a question like this. There's absolutely no research effort shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a css rule

```
ul.textMenu a.clicked

{   
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff5c00;

}
```

and then some js

```
$('ul.textMenu a').click( function() {
    // Remove the class clicked so that we have only one clicked item
    // Since there might be more than one ul i finde the parent.
    $(this).closest('ul.textMenu').find('a').removeClass('clicked')
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
} );
```

Comment: fast answer, and upvoted ;) I would have forgotten the removeClass

Comment: Except this won't remove class from the correct group of `<a>` elements. Since the `<ul>` has a class that is being targeted, that means there may several on the page. If you just use `$("ul.textMenu a").removeClass("clicked")`, it removes all occurrences on the page that are in a `<ul>` with the class `clicked` - not just the clicked element's group.

Comment: @ianpgall i haven't the precise markup but changed my answer in a way that should work

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('ul.textMenu a').click(function () {
    jQuery('ul.textMenu a').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The set your css for ul.textMenu a.active to keep the CSS border